# How to make an xbox game with actionscript?

Tags: flash, actionscript, export, xbox

Is it possible to use actionscript to export to xbox? So, can I make an iPhone application (AIR) and export it to the xbox indie game store somehow? If so, how would I go about doing this. I am pretty sure the game castle crashers used actionscript as their whole game was made in flash but I do not understand how I would link the xbox controller to this (I can link it to a keyboard easily of course). And would I just export a huge display size and the tv/xbox would automatically downscale it?

Here is the game castle crashers for some reference: http://www.castlecrashers.com/

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Im sure its not possible as you cant just make one script in flash and export it to Xbox, Xbox games contain a lot of various files for different things.But what you can do is make flash content to be imported into a Xbox game for example the menu, this is also present with playstation 3.

Im not too familiar with xbox native environment but i know several games contain flash content with in the game from interactive menu's and console widgets..

Rugby league live (xbox game) uses this for there main title menu.